# Can’t connect to Microsoft SQL Server using Tableau online

Tags: sql-server, tableau-api

I am getting the following error when I am going to create a new data source by connecting to SQL on premises database using Tableau online.

> Can’t connect to Microsoft SQL Server
>   Detailed Error Message
>   There was an unknown connection error to the database. The error message below has additional information, but you might need to ask the database administrator to review the database logs.  %1 
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]MAX_PROVS: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified [xFFFFFFFF]. 
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
>   Unable to connect to the Microsoft SQL Server server "my server name". Check that the server is running and that you have access privileges to the requested database.
>   
> 2019-02-25 07:38:34.520, (XHObPax0w59qQPz8O0dV6QAAAIk,0:0)

Any idea to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use 'Tableau Bridge' to connect from online to on-prem.

https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/online/en-us/qs_refresh_local_data.htm

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that you need to whitelist the Tableau Online IP addresses in your SQL Server instance. See the link for the addresses.

[Tableau Whitelist Info](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/online/en-us/to_keep_data_fresh.htm#whitelist)